# Erro com PHPMailer - Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/intergroup/public_html/view/envio_contato.php on line 90

Tags: php

This is the message i am getting on my log.

> Fatal error:  Class 'PHPMailer' not found in
>   /home/intergroup/public_html/view/envio_contato.php on line 90

But when i press crtl+g on sublime he finds the classes with means the includes are correct.

this is my code: (This text right here is just because StackOverflor dont allows me to post my question, he says i have too much code and i need to explain better and give more details, so: How can i solve this problem, like, what kind of actions can i take to debug?)

```
<?php

$robots = 'nao';
include '_definicoes.php';
include_once '_header.php';

$pagina_atual = 'envio_contato';

$link_encaminhar_erro = $dominio;
$link_encaminhar_concluido = $dominio;

$title = $nome_site;
$description = $description;
$keywords = $keywords;

// resposta vazia
$response = null;
// verifique a chave secreta
// $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
// if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // se submetido, verifique a resposta
    // if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    //     $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    //             $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    //     );
    // }
    // if ($response == null) {
    //     echo "<script>alert('Por favor assinale o campo de verificação!');history.back();</script>";
    //     exit;
    // }
    // Verifica a resposta do Captcha
if ($response != null && $response->success) {
    $nome_site_utf8 = utf8_decode($nome_site);
    $nome_contato = utf8_decode($_POST['nome_contato']);
    $email_contato = $_POST['email_contato'];
    $telefone_contato = $_POST['telefone_contato'];
    $assunto_contato_utf8 = utf8_decode($_POST['assunto_contato']);
    $mensagem_contato = utf8_decode(nl2br($_POST['mensagem_contato']));
    $link_anterior = $_POST['link_anterior'];
        //checando se o e-mail é válido
    $email_contato = strtolower($email_contato);
    $qtd_email = explode("@", $email_contato);
    if (count($qtd_email) <= 1) {
            //se não possuir @ aparece a mensagem
        echo "<script>alert('Por favor, insira um e-mail válido!');history.back();</script>";
        exit;
    } else if (count($qtd_email) == 2) {
        $ip = gethostbyname($qtd_email[1]);
            //função gethostbyname recupera o ip do domínio, se não tiver ip aparece a mensagem
        if ($ip == $qtd_email[1]) {
            echo "<script>alert('Por favor, insira um e-mail válido!');history.back();</script>";
            exit;
        }
    }
    if ($assunto_contato_utf8 == '') {
        echo "<script>alert('Por favor, preencha um Assunto!');history.back();</script>";
        exit;
    }
    $nome_contato = ucwords(strtolower($nome_contato));
    $email_conteudo = "<html>
    <body>
    <font face='Arial' style='color: #606060;'>
    <table border='0' style='width: 400px;>
    <tr> <td style='height: 40px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>Assunto:</b><br/> $assunto_contato_utf8<br/><br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='height: 40px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>Nome:</b><br/> $nome_contato<br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='height: 40px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>E-mail:</b><br/> $email_contato<br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='height: 40px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>Telefone:</b><br/> $telefone_contato<br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>Mensagem:</b><br/> $mensagem_contato<br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='height: 20px;'></td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='height: 40px; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #606060;'> <b>P&aacute;gina de Refer&ecirc;ncia:</b><br/> $link_anterior<br/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td style='padding-top: 20px;'></td> </tr>
    </table>
    </font>
    </body>
    </html>";
    /** Montagem e Envio do e-mail * */
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    include 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    include 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';


}

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
//$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = $mail_host;
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = $mail_port;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $mail_user;
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = $mail_pass;
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom("$mail_send", "$nome_contato");
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo("$email_contato", "$nome_contato");
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress("$email_formulario", "$nome_site_utf8");
$mail->addAddress("suporte@cgdw.com.br,suporte1@cgdw.com.br");
//$mail->addAddress("$email_formulario2", "$nome_site");
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $assunto_contato_utf8 . " - ".$nome_site_utf8;
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->Body = $email_conteudo;
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "<script>alert('Desculpe, ocorreu um erro ao enviar, tente novamente!');window.open('" . $link_encaminhar_erro . "', '_self');</script>";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Sua mensagem foi enviada, agradecemos seu contato!');window.open('" . $link_encaminhar_concluido . "', '_self');</script>";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: You will get more and faster help if you describe your problem in English. It's hard to help if one can't read the language. From what I can read in your code I'd suggest you are missing the `require`for `PHPMailer` classes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is an English website. Please translate your question to English. If needed you can install [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) in your browser that will help you correct your language. - Bienvenido a SO. Este es un sitio web en inglés. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta al inglés. Si es necesario, puede instalar [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) en su navegador que lo ayudará a corregir su idioma.

Comment: ok thanks guys.. i am sorry. i will write in english for now on.

Comment: Have you checked whether all files are properly uploaded to your webserver?

Comment: You are actually including the PHPMailer class somewhere? I mean, like opening one of your includes, is there a class inside them? And it's `PHPMailer()` not `PHPMailer`.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem this way : 
Delete ALL de old code (that was made for someone else) and star fresh. ending up with this code that work

```
<?php
```

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerT.class.php';

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LfEGGoUAAAAAOQQe3y9EkneINSI9bEQLYOATrfr&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']));
if (!is_object($json) || $json->success != true) {
    echo "<script>alert('Por favor assinale o campo de verificação!');history.back();</script>";
}

$nome_contato = ($_POST['nome_contato']);
$telefone_contato = ($_POST['telefone_contato']);
$email_contato = ($_POST['email_contato']);
$assunto_contato = ($_POST['assunto_contato']);
$mensagem_contato = ($_POST['mensagem_contato']);
$Content = "
<p><b>Nome:</b> " . ($nome_contato) . "</p>
<p><b>Telefone:</b> " . ($telefone_contato) . "</p>
<p><b>Email:</b> " . ($email_contato) . "</p>
<p><b>Assunto:</b> " . ($assunto_contato) . "</p>
<p><b>Mensagem:</b> " . ($mensagem_contato) . "</p>";
$PHPMailer = new PHPMailerT();
$PHPMailer->IsSMTP();
$PHPMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$PHPMailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
$PHPMailer->SMTPSecure = '';
$PHPMailer->Port = 587;
$PHPMailer->Host = 'mail.server.com.br';
$PHPMailer->Username = 'envio@server.com.br';
$PHPMailer->Password = '';
$PHPMailer->Subject = 'Contato do Site - Intergroup';
$PHPMailer->SetFrom($email_contato, $nome_contato);
$PHPMailer->AddAddress('contato@server.com.br');
$PHPMailer->AddAddress('suporte1@cgdw.com.br');
$ContentSend = "<table width=\"600\">";
$ContentSend .= "<tr>";
$ContentSend .= "<td>$Content<td>";
$ContentSend .= "</tr>";
$ContentSend .= "</table>";
$PHPMailer->MsgHTML($ContentSend);
    if ($PHPMailer->Send()) {
        echo "<script>alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso.');history.back();</script>";
    } else {
        $msgReturn = '<div class="msgErro">Ocorreu um erro, tente mais tarde!</div>';
    }
}

echo $msgReturn;
?>
```